# Does the "delete" statement doubly free an object?

Tags: vector, stl, erase

Does the "delete" statement below "doubly free" an object?

```
(...object_list is a global vector<object*>...)

vector< object * >::iterator     it, eit, iter;
object *p_object;
vector< object * >   dead_objects;

it  = object_list_.begin();
eit = object_list_.end();

//---collect pointers of all dead objects to dead_objects vector
for ( ; it != eit; it++ )
{
    p_object = *it;
    if ( p_object->is_dead() == false )
        continue;

    dead_objects.push_back( p_object );
}

//---free every dead object from the global object_list
for ( iter = dead_objects.begin(); iter != dead_objects.end(); iter++ )
{
    p_object = *iter;

    it  = object_list_.begin();
    eit = object_list_.end();

    for ( ; it != eit; it++ )
    {
        if ( *it != p_object )
            continue;

        object_list_.erase( it );
        delete p_object;
        break;
    }
}
```

I ask the question because the `erase()` statement above should have called the destructor of an object and freed it already, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`erase()` does call the destructor on the object, but the destructor of a pointer type (such as `object *` here) does nothing -- it does NOT call delete on the pointer.  If you want it to call delete, you need to use some object (such as `auto_ptr<object *>`) which does call delete.

Comment: thank you for the answer!!

i had the question because in another program i use map<int,object*> and the program crashed when i dereferenced an object* after i called erase() to remove the object* from the map. (i am using VC++ 6) so i wonder if vector<object*>.erase() frees the object too.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear not; if you have a vector of pointers to objects, calling erase() to remove one of them simply removes the pointer from the vector. You are still required to delete it yourself - this is because STL containers are designed primarily to collect objects by value.

Just a couple of suggestions - IMO your code would be clearer if you used STL algorithms like `std::find` instead of looping over all your vectors by hand. I'm not sure what the point of dead_objects vs object_list is - you don't seem to gain anything by storing them in the temporary vector, but something may have been lost in copying the code to SO. And `std::vector` is not optimal for lots of random erasures like this since `erase` runs in linear time - `std::remove` followed by `erase` would be a more efficient approach. For example:

```
for(vector<object*>::iterator it = object_list.begin(); it != object_list.end(); ++it) {
    if((*it)->is_dead()) {
        delete *it;
        *it = NULL;
    }
}
object_list.erase(std::remove(object_list.begin(), object_list.end(), NULL), object_list.end());
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! but doesn't your last statement 

  object_list.erase(std::remove(object_list.begin(),    
         object_list.end(), NULL), object_list.end());

erase ALL objects, dead and alive?

Comment: No - `remove` removes all the elements from the list equal to NULL and returns an iterator to just after the last valid element. The `erase` call then truncates the vector to this new length.